# Dropdown plus manual text field in angular form

Tags: angular, forms, angular-material, angular2-forms, angular-formbuilder

I am beginner to angular and I have angular form in my application where i want to add dropdown field , if user entered value does not exist in dropdown then allow him to enter some new value and we get its value for further use.

Comment: What's stopping you from accomplishing this goal of yours?

Comment: @R.Richards Hi, I am facing challenge to do it , as i am beginner and dont know how to make this way

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.